# "Савва (Сербский) был рукоположен архиепископом"?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

Неманичи:

> Не одобряя политики Стефана и поведения Вукана, Савва остановит
>   кровопролитие, утихомирит вражду. А после отправится в Никею, где
>   испросит у патриарха разрешение на учреждение независимой Сербской
>   церкви. Его просьба оказалась более чем уместна в момент очередной
>   обширной международной политической интриги, и Савва был рукоположен
>   архиепископом.

Рукоположен - через *ё*: рукоположён?

Comment: А где ответ на шапку вопроса? Ё шло довеском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить электронной версии словаря синонимов Тришина, то у причастия рукополож**е**нный есть "синоним" *рукополож**ё**нный* (что должно отражаться и на краткой форме).

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/155541/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Можно предположить, что вариант с **ё** появился в *светских* текстах, и позже церковного варианта. Другое упоминание слова с **ё** есть в книге "Два века русской буквы Ё: история и словарь" (Пчелов, Чумаков, 2000). В прочих книгах этот вариант (записи?) почти не встречается.

Answer (score 0):

Практически везде предлагается форма рукоположён, например:

[https://kartaslov.ru/как-правильно-пишется-слово/рукоположённый](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

https://slovar.cc/rus/zaliznyak/1536534.html